# jQuery elements not appearing on Django page

Tags: jquery, django, python-2.7, django-floppyforms

I am trying to implement the [Slider from django-floppyforms](http://django-floppyforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html#a-slider). However my page only displays a single empty text box when I use the examples given. When I render it using `{{form.as_p}}` I can only get the native slider to work but I I would really like the JS functionality.

I have a copy of `jquery-1.11.1.min.js` downloaded from http://jquery.com/download/ Its filepath is `floppyform_test/static/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js`
`floppy_project/src/floppyform_test/static/js

I think it might be a problem with my jQuery filepath (I have tried many variations) or my views.py

I haven't really used JavaScript before but here is what I have tried.

**views.py**

```
def sview(request):
    jquery_slider = Slider()
    native_slider = SlideForm()

    return render(request, 'slider.html', {
                                           'jquery_slider': jquery_slider,   
                                           'native_slider': native_slider,             
                                           })
```

**slider.html** (adapted from [original](http://django-floppyforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html#a-slider))

```
{# slider.html #}
{% include "floppyforms/input.html" %}
<div id="{{ attrs.id }}-slider"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }} /static/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var type = $('<input type="range" />').attr('type');
    if (type == 'text') { // No HTML5 support
      $('#{{ attrs.id }}').attr("readonly", true);
      $('#{{ attrs.id }}-slider').slider({
        {% if value %}value: {{ value }},{% endif %}
        min: {{ attrs.min }},
        max: {{ attrs.max }},
        step: {{ attrs.step }},
        slide: function(event, ui) {
          $('#{{ attrs.id }}').val(ui.value);
        }
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

**forms.py** (copied from [original](http://django-floppyforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html#a-slider))

```
import floppyforms as forms

class Slider(forms.RangeInput):
    min = 5
    max = 20
    step = 5
    template_name = 'slider.html'

    class Media:
        js = (
            'js/jquery.min.js',
            'js/jquery-ui.min.js',
        )
        css = {
            'all': (
                'css/jquery-ui.css',
            )
        }

class SlideForm(forms.Form):
    num = forms.IntegerField(widget=Slider)

    def clean_num(self):
        num = self.cleaned_data['num']
        if not 5 <= num <= 20:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Enter a value between 5 and 20")

        if not num % 5 == 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Enter a multiple of 5")
        return num
```

Any help is greatly appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things:

1. Can you find the jquery file at the {{static_url}}/static.... path? If you've set your static_url to be /static/, you don't need the /static added again.
2. You've declared more jquery in your Slider widget, but its a different path and version to your declaration in your template, so you'll get a clash.
3. Don't declare your jquery file as you have done - put it in the head of the doc, then wite your ad-hoc script using the  $(document).ready(function(){})  syntax

Comment: I'm excepting this as the right answer as it has pointed out several mistakes in my code. Ill post back with a full solution when i get it.